# Reality Composer Replay: [MOVReaderInterface]: Error: Cannot grab metadata. Unknown metadata stream 'Location'

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit, realitykit

I try to record scenes with Reality Composer on my iPhone 12 Pro, version 16.1 and I want to replay it in my ARKit/RealityKit application to test some scenarios. I have had a couple of issues with this.

First of all, the Reality Composer iOS app (latest version 1.5.3 as of writing this) works fine so far. BUT when I do recordings with location access allowed (instead of "never") and then exporting the files (via AirDrop) to my computer and replaying them in my Xcode project, does not work at all. It crashes almost immediately. Recordings with location access disabled work ... but they throw a whole lot of errors in my console.

`2022-11-27 03:46:03.246713+0100 mt-test-1[2888:151328] ⛔️⛔️⛔️ ERROR [MOVReaderInterface]: Error Domain=com.apple.AppleCV3DMOVKit.readererror Code=9 "Location: Error Domain=com.apple.videoeng.streamreaderwarning Code=0 "Cannot grab metadata. Unknown metadata stream 'Location'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot grab metadata. Unknown metadata stream 'Location'.}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Location: Error Domain=com.apple.videoeng.streamreaderwarning Code=0 "Cannot grab metadata. Unknown metadata stream 'Location'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot grab metadata. Unknown metadata stream 'Location'.}} ⛔️⛔️⛔️`

Since replay itself seems to work this issue is more about cluttering my console rendering basically useless.

I also tried to add `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` to my `Info.plist` but this didn't change anything. Does someone have some insight on what the problem is here?